# The application /Applications/Preview.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

Im developing an algorithm that automatically draws plans for my business using python PIL Image Draw
I want to show the image but I get the following error

`The application /Applications/Preview.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Preview.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/Preview.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/Preview.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003e4c0f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

This is the code

```
    f = io.BytesIO()
    img = Image.new('RGB', (img_x, img_y), '#FFFFFF')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    ...

    img.save(f, 'PNG')
    img.show()
    f.seek(0)

    return base64.b64encode(f.read())
```

I can't change the file format or anything like this since im putting this into a module and I need a base64string for it to work

Im using an 8 core Intel MacBook Pro with macOS Monterey 12.1

Comment: The Preview app has moved to `/System/Applications/Preview.app`. Try upgrading your Pillow.

Comment: Check your current version with `python -m PIL`

Comment: as this solved the question (upgrading to 3.9) I would like to mark it as correct. If you want the reward, add it as an answer and I will mark it. Otherwise I will add the answer myself

Comment: No problem, I added it. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Preview app has moved to `/System/Applications/Preview.app`

Try upgrading your Pillow.

Check your current version with:

```
python -m PIL    # or "python3 -m PIL" depending what you use
```