# Trying to upgrade PIL fails Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Im trying to upgrade PIL [because of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931618/the-application-applications-preview-app-cannot-be-opened-for-an-unexpected-rea) (I now have a new machine) however, if I run the same command I get the following error

```
❯ python3 -m PIL
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named
PIL.__main__; 'PIL' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I have also tried using other names for PIL, but that didn't work either

```
❯ python3 -m Pillow
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named Pillow

❯ python3 -m Image
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named Image
```

Im using Python 3.7 on MacOS 12.4, and I have to stay on Python 3.7 because of the clients dependencies.
Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) hasn't been upgraded in 11 years. It was replaced by Pillow, which is installed just like any other package using `pip`. Pillow isn't an alias for PIL

Comment: BTW Python 3.7 reaches End-Of-Life in 1 year, so you need to start thinking about upgrading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade pillow
```